# What could be causing this printer ghosting?

Tags: printer

My laser printer is a Samsung CLP-310 and every page I print have these ugly ghosting artifacts:

- A random document I printed and annotated. You can see ghosting happening about 20cm above, and another ghost about 20cm below
  [image: page0001-annotated.jpg]
- A test document I created to showcase the ghosting in hopefully a clearer manner
  [image: page0002.jpg]
- A white page printed after the test page. I had to play with the scanner contrast so that the band artifact are visible but don't trust the color. (i'm not sure this one is related to the ghosting but here it is anyway)
  [image: page0003.jpg]

The ghosting happens within a page, and the previous page isn't ghosted in the next page

Original source files:

- test imprimante.docx https://drive.google.com/file/d/1EONEuTJlYRBQDQ5fn5SyWIK3fL9yZv2s/view?usp=sharing
- the other file (screenshot):
  [image]

Answer (score 1):

That looks like the drum inside is dirty, picking up toner and depositing that further down on the same page/next pages.

You will have to clean it. You can find multiple instruction videos on Youtube showing how to do that.

Even if this is not the main problem, cleaning the printer will at least eliminate dirt as a cause and make it easier to detect any other problems (if present).

Comment: Thanks, Will try to clean it, once I get the alcohol isopropyl recommanded to clean it !

Comment: @BiAiB isopropyl is available from any pharmacy. You don't need much of it. A small bottle will do.

Answer (score 0):

TLDR: replace the cyan toner cartridge.

I'll start by saying that my initial though was "it has to be the fuser" - until I read that the ghosts only appear on the same page, not on a subsequent one.

That leaves 2 other possibilities: the imaging unit and the toner cartridges.

The Samsung CLP-310 is a 4-pass printer. That means that, to print colour, it runs through the image 4 times, each with its own toner. These 4 images are accumulated onto the imaging unit. The final image is then transferred to the paper. As all 4 are combined on the imaging unit, I think we can rule that out as the culprit as well.

That leaves the toners. In your case, it appears that the ghosts are cyan coloured. That tells me the cyan toner cartridge is your problem.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually there is a ghost for all four colors (you can see the ghosted red "MI" in page one, which is a mix of red+yellow+black I think) . Unfortunately the scanner pass had too much luminosity/constrast, erasing the faint ghosts on the second page